# routerLink with singleline if and child route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

i want check if is login [routerLink] link to profile basket else link to loaclbasket :

```
[routerLink]="[isLogin == true ? '/Profile' ,'Basket'  : 'LocalBasket']"
```

but throw error!(i dont want use *ngIf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
[routerLink]="isLogin == true ? ['/Profile' ,'Basket'] : ['LocalBasket']"
```

Comment: tnxx my frieeeend :D